# How to deploy a sails app built with www --prod?

Tags: sails.js

The command line:

```
sails www --prod
```

builds a concatenated minified version of the app in the www folder.  It then exits (does not continue to serve after building).

How can that version of the app be deployed in the cloud (ex. OpenShift)?  Either with or without Grunt.

Answer (score 0):

At openShift you could simply deploy your Sails app and set NODE_ENV = production.

Than this would happen:
- On lift, Sails build your Site (into .tmp) and use this files for serving to the client

Comment: Thanks; yes i get that; but the question is more about www --prod <- what's it for, how is it used, etc.

Comment: That is only for you to see what sails would produce in productiuon in the .tmp-folder